# Flutter web reads from the page where it is located

Tags: html, flutter, web

When you develop a flutter app, it´s possible to connect with the native language of iOS or Android, nevertheless have anyone thought that a web application could need read anything from the web in which it is?

For example, If you have a website and you want to have a share an app feacture in a web (inside of a iFrame), maybe could be neccessary to read any kind of information in order to make run the flutter web. As a code or a piece information with which the flutter web can work.

Do someone have this kind of question? Any answer?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but you might mean something like that: https://dart.dev/web/js-interop ?

Comment: It makes sense that flutter web uses a js package since android is done in java

Comment: Exactly frankenapps, I was trying to do that,  I haven't notice this package.

Comment: Are there any other package for reading the cookies of the web in which is located throught iFrame?